# Thickbox not closing after inserting media in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, thickbox

I'm using the Wordpress Thickbox to try and retrun the value of the images that a user wants to select (when they click 'Insert into Post'), but the Thickbox is not closing, just showing as any empty white box.

The field `$('#office-image input#image')` exists, and Firebug is not reporitng any errors.

I'm not sure why this is not working, so any help is appriciated. Thanks.

```
window.send_to_editor = function(html){

    var image_url = $('img', html).attr('src');

    $('#office-image input#image').val(image_url);
    tb_remove();

}
```

Comment: check error console may be happen due to jQuery

check via firebug Console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
window.original_send_to_editor = window.send_to_editor;
window.send_to_editor = function (html) {
    var fileInput = jQuery(fileInput_id);
    if (fileInput) {
        fileurl = jQuery('img', html).attr('src');
        jQuery(fileInput).val(fileurl);
        tb_remove();

    } else {
        window.original_send_to_editor(html);
    }
};
```

I am using above script for that and its working fine

Comment: The fact that you were using `jQuery`, not `$` led me to the answer. It was becasue I forget to pass `$` through `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`. Thanks.